# What is the big o notation of this algorithm?

Tags: big-o

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for(int x = i; x < n; ++x)
    {
        // work... 
    }
}
```

What is the big o notation for this type of algorithm? Also, please explain to me how you came up with the solution.

Also, sorry for the vague title but I didn't know the name of this type of algorithm.

Here is what I tried:

If n is:

1, there will be 1 work execution.

2, there will be 3 work execution.

3, there will be 6 work execution.

4, there will be 10 work execution.

5, there will be 15 work execution.

People in the comment say it is n^2 but the numbers I'm getting don't match the result as 5^2 is 25 and not 15

Comment: `O(stop being lazy, stop cheating, and do your own homework)`

Comment: The answer will be `n+n-1+n-2+...+1 = O(n^2)`

Comment: @MarcB I'm doing my homework, if I knew the answer why would I ask the internet?

Comment: you're not asking for help, you're demanding the answer. We'd be happy to help, if you'd shown if you'd put ANY effort into this whatsoever. e.g. "I think it's O(n log n) because...".

Comment: @MarcB Edited to show my effort

Comment: See my answer for the derivation of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O notation is derived from calculating the time complexity. You must take into account the amount of work in which your algorithm is doing.

Please see below my answer in which I derive Big 0. This is using `LateX` which is a nice tool to write equations.

*Notes*

- The giant `E` like symbol - is called a Sigma. This is a mathematical symbol that is used in writing up algorithms to annotate a looping function. Think of it as your `for` - the bottom term is like your `i=0` and the top term is like your `i < n`.
- The `(n-1)` represents the work of the inner loop. - to calculate this, we break the equation into two separate Sigmas - as `i` is more complex to derive.
- notice how the inner loop does not run `n` times but `n-i`. Also, line (3) - to understand what `i` is - we use Summations (Law 6 maybe?).

To get n^2 - we eliminate constants from the equation aswell as terms that do not dominate the growth of the function.

[image: Deriving Big O]

Comment: Given the OPs demonstrated skill level, there is very little chance of this answer being understood without more explanation.

Comment: Ok understood - will try and add appropriate "commentary" to what it is doing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be O(n^2/2) because when n is 5000 than the number of work being called is 12502500 which is (5000^2)/2

Comment: You eliminate constants to get Big O; i.e eliminate the `/2`

Comment: Oh, I see, that is what I didn't understand. Why do we do that?

Comment: I have not but if you have good source on it than I'm willing to read.

Comment: A quick Google will bring you hundreds, if not thousands of good sources. Why do you need to know the Big O notation if you do not understand what it is?

Comment: I'm trying to learn it. I never went to school for programming and I learned everything from the internet but the big o notation doesn't make a lot of sense to me.